# Symfony EasyAdminBundle markdown editor

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm using EasyAdminBundle for Symfony2. I wanna edit long text in some nice and simple markdown editor, not in textarea. I was unable to find setting in config.yml which would do this change. It is even possible in default installation, or I must install more packages? Any advice how to do it clean and simply?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We don't provide built-in support for Markdown editors, but we integrate nicely with the WYSIWYG CKEditor editor provided by IvoryCKEditorBundle. See https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/tutorials/wysiwyg-editor.md

Maybe you can configure CKEditor to use it as Markdown editor or you can get inspiration to integrate your own editor.

Comment: CKEditor is perfect, but I have instruction to use only some markdown editor. So there is no simple way how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be:
https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/tutorials/wysiwyg-editor.md

If that is not enough for your needs you may have to look deeper on how to define your own types like 'ckeditor' or 'vich_image' (used when using easyadmin in cunjuncton with VichUploader).

I'll take a short lookaround if there's a doc on how to do that exactly.
Edit: 
There's only a doc on how to define custom properties for list/search/show views. 
https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/tutorials/custom-property-options.md

But taking this as a starting point and take a look at the ckeditor integration should give you all necessary pointers on how to do it.

regards

Comment: You was faster then Javier :-) and given a more complete answer.

Comment: Ok, but that don't solve my problem, because I must strictly use some kind of markdown editor, no WYSIWYG is allowed. I know it can sound strange, but that's my current situation.